# Jquery ajax, js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small problem that I can not solve. I want that when an element is clicked (this element deletes a product from the cart) a loading spinner ("remove-spinner") appears and it goes away when the ajax function ends. So far I could make the spinner variable (spn) appear with fadeIn, but it does not disappear after ajax deletes the item from the cart, it is activated for the other elements that are in the cart. Thanks so much!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
carttotalamount();

$(document).on("click", ".removecartitem", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var rurl = $t.attr("data-remove-url");
    var delrowid = $t.attr("datarowid");
    var qty = $t.attr("dataitemqty");
    var spn = $(".remover-spinner");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rurl,
        success: function(data) { 
            $('.'+delrowid).fadeOut(200, function(){
                spn.fadeIn(100)
                $('.'+delrowid).remove(spn); carttotalamount();
            }); 

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: for the spinner use ajaxstart and ajaxstop events to trigger the spinner

Comment: Spinner is in the row? So only select the one that is in the row, not all elements

Comment: or you can use beforestart and completed callbacks to add and remove the spinner. completed will be called in both cases if it succeeds or if it fails

Comment: Your question title doesn't describe your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use `beforeSend` to `fadeIn` the `remover-spinner`. And remove it when the ajax `success`.

```
 beforeSend: function(){
            spn.fadeIn(100)
 },
 success: function(data) { 
            $('.'+delrowid).fadeOut(200, function(){
                spn.fadeOut(100)
                carttotalamount();
            }); 

        }
```

> beforeSend Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings ) A
>   pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in
>   jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to
>   set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as
>   arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend
>   function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend
>   option will be called regardless of the type of request.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi! thanks. appears and disappears effectively, but when I click on element one, the rotary control is activated on all elements, but I will need the rotary control to be activated only on the element that I click

Comment: Use $(this) for access to the ".removecartitem" clicked